# Text spacing altered when using minipage

Tags: spacing, minipage

Why does the spacing between words alter when using minipage function ?

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 14pt, oneside]{article}
\usepackage{soul} % Used for the title name (eg. title)
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{marvosym} % add the symbols for email and phone contact data
\usepackage{fancyhdr} % Required for the footer
\usepackage{tabularx} % Nicer table style than the default
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{abstract}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor} % Allows the definition of hex colors

\definecolor{headings}{HTML}{701112} % Dark red color for headings
\definecolor{text1}{HTML}{2b2b2b} % Main document font color, off-black

\usepackage[none]{hyphenat} % Prevents hyphenation in text


\usepackage[margin=10mm,bottom=20mm]{geometry}

\linespread{1.1} % Line spacing

% Sections formatting
\titleformat{\section}{\color{headings}
\scshape\Large\raggedright}{}{0em}{}[\color{black}\titlerule]

\pagestyle{fancy}

% Prevents overfull hbox and vbox
\hbadness=10000
\hfuzz=50pt
\vbadness=10000
\vfuzz=50pt


\renewcommand\headrulewidth{0pt} % Size of the header rule
\renewcommand\footrulewidth{0.001pt} % Size of the footer rule

\usepackage[pdfborder={0 0 0},bookmarks=true,pdftitle={CV},pdfauthor={first last},pdfsubject={Curriculum Vitae},pdfcreator={www.abhij.com},pdfproducer={www.abhij.com}]{hyperref}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%  CV STARTS HERE  %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%  NAME AND CONTACT  %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{center}
%Uncomment below to color the \textsl{\textit{\textbf{\emph{\textsc{\textsc{\textsc{headings}}}}}}}
%\color{headings}
%\textsc{\Huge{\so{Abhilash Sukumari}}} \\ % Use for extra spacing inbetween the words.
\textsc{\Huge{First Last}} \\
\vspace{0pt}
\color{text1}{\Large\Telefon} (Area code)-xxx-xxxx \hfill {\Large\Writinghand} Street, Apt \# XXXX, City, EX-7xxxx \hfill {\Large\Letter} \href{mailto:email@email.com}{email@email.com} 

%%%%%% SKILLS  %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Start the left-hand side of the page
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.48\textwidth}
\vspace{0pt} % Trick for alignment
\section{Skills}
\begin{tabularx}{1\linewidth\centering\arraybackslash}{>{\raggedright\scshape}p{2.5cm}X}
\textbf{Something} & Something, Something, Something, Something, C, C++\\
\textbf{Others}  & \LaTeX, \textsc{html}\\
\textbf{Others}  & Something Something (Something), Something Something (Something Something Something)
\end{tabularx}
\end{minipage} % End left-hand side of the page
\hfill
%%%%%%  Tool proficiency  %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Start the right-hand side of the page
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.48\textwidth} 
\vspace{0pt} %trick for alignment
\section{Tools} 
\begin{tabularx}{1\linewidth}{>{\raggedright\scshape}p{1cm}X}
\textbf{Tool}    & Something-Something (Something) $\&$ Something Something \\
\textbf{Others}    & Something, Something Something, Something, Something Something, Something-Something, Something \\
\end{tabularx}

\end{minipage} % End right-hand side of the page

%%%%%%  END  %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image: 1]

Comment: You don't need dollar to use ampersand. Just use `\&`.

Comment: The paragraph can't be typeset any better than that. It has nothing to do with `minipage`, other than because the line width is small. You should set those paragraphs ragged right.

Comment: Otherwise don't use the option `none` when loading `hyphenat` and let it hyphenate inside that table.

Answer (score 1):

You have conflicting requests: if you disable hyphenation, you have to expect bad word spacing, unless you typeset your narrow columns ragged right.

The columns could be a bit wider if you remove the padding at the sides. I added

```
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
```

and changed the calls to `tabularx` into

```
\begin{tabularx}{1\linewidth}{>{@{}>{\bfseries}lY@{}}
```

Note that the default fonts don't have small caps bold face. If you use a different font family that has, just add `\scshape` after `\bfseries`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 14pt, oneside]{article}
\usepackage{soul} % Used for the title name (eg. title)
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{marvosym} % add the symbols for email and phone contact data
\usepackage{fancyhdr} % Required for the footer
\usepackage{tabularx} % Nicer table style than the default
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{abstract}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor} % Allows the definition of hex colors

\definecolor{headings}{HTML}{701112} % Dark red color for headings
\definecolor{text1}{HTML}{2b2b2b} % Main document font color, off-black

\usepackage[none]{hyphenat} % Prevents hyphenation in text


\usepackage[margin=10mm,bottom=20mm]{geometry}

\linespread{1.1} % Line spacing

% Sections formatting
\titleformat{\section}{\color{headings}
\scshape\Large\raggedright}{}{0em}{}[\color{black}\titlerule]

\pagestyle{fancy}


\renewcommand\headrulewidth{0pt} % Size of the header rule
\renewcommand\footrulewidth{0.001pt} % Size of the footer rule

\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}

\usepackage[pdfborder={0 0 0},bookmarks=true,pdftitle={CV},pdfauthor={first last},pdfsubject={Curriculum Vitae},pdfcreator={www.abhij.com},pdfproducer={www.abhij.com}]{hyperref}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%  CV STARTS HERE  %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%  NAME AND CONTACT  %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{center}
%Uncomment below to color the \textsl{\textit{\textbf{\emph{\textsc{\textsc{\textsc{headings}}}}}}}
%\color{headings}
%\textsc{\Huge\so{Abhilash Sukumari}} \\ % Use for extra spacing inbetween the words.
\textsc{\Huge First Last} \\
\vspace{0pt}
\color{text1}{\Large\Telefon} (Area code)-xxx-xxxx \hfill {\Large\Writinghand} Street, Apt \# XXXX, City, EX-7xxxx \hfill {\Large\Letter} \href{mailto:email@email.com}{email@email.com} 

%%%%%% SKILLS  %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Start the left-hand side of the page
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.48\textwidth}
\vspace{0pt} % Trick for alignment
\section{Skills}
\begin{tabularx}{1\linewidth}{@{}>{\bfseries}lY@{}}
Something & Something, Something, Something, Something, C, C++\\
Others  & \LaTeX, \textsc{html}\\
Others  & Something Something (Something), Something Something (Something Something Something)
\end{tabularx}
\end{minipage} % End left-hand side of the page
\hfill
%%%%%%  Tool proficiency  %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Start the right-hand side of the page
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.48\textwidth} 
\vspace{0pt} %trick for alignment
\section{Tools} 
\begin{tabularx}{1\linewidth}{@{}>{\bfseries}lY@{}}
Tool    & Something-Something (Something) \& Something Something \\
Others  & Something, Something Something, Something, Something Something, Something-Something, Something \\
\end{tabularx}

\end{minipage} % End right-hand side of the page

%%%%%%  END  %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]